# 1054 - Unknow colunm in on clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

o que há de errado nessa consulta?

```
SELECT 
  clientes.idClientes, 
    clientes.nome, 
    clientes.bloqueado, 
    planosclientes.idPlanos, 
    planos.nome, 
    enderecos.bairro, 
    enderecos.cidade                    
FROM 
    planosclientes INNER JOIN clientes  ON planosclientes.idClientes       =  clientes.idClientes                 AND
    planosclientes INNER JOIN planos    ON planosclientes.idPlanos         =  planos.idPlanos                     AND
    planosclientes INNER JOIN enderecos ON planosclientes.idPlanosClientes =  enderecos.idPlanosClientes
WHERE 
    clientes.bloqueado = 's' AND 
    enderecos.tipoEndereco = 'i'
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Unknow colunm 'planosclientes' in on clause.
```

Mas não tem nehuma coluna 'planosclientes' nas clausulas on. O que tem são tabelas 'planosclientes'.

Que erro é esse?

Comment: Sua consulta parece errada, tem um `AND` la no fim comparando com nada. Identa melhor o código.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que dessa forma a consulta está correta, não precisa repetir o nome da em cada `INNER JOIN`

> Unknow colunm 'planosclientes' in on clause.

O erro acontece porque a sintaxe diz, junte com a tabela cliente onde os ids sejam iguais **e** planosclientes(é uma tabela e não uma coluna)

```
planosclientes INNER JOIN clientes
ON planosclientes.idClientes =  clientes.idClientes AND planosclientes
-----------------------------------------------------^----^(tabela)
```

Mude para:

```
SELECT 
  clientes.idClientes, 
    clientes.nome, 
    clientes.bloqueado, 
    planosclientes.idPlanos, 
    planos.nome, 
    enderecos.bairro, 
    enderecos.cidade                    
FROM 
    planosclientes
    INNER JOIN clientes ON planosclientes.idClientes = clientes.idClientes 
    INNER JOIN planos ON planosclientes.idPlanos = planos.idPlanos 
    INNER JOIN enderecos ON planosclientes.idPlanosClientes =  enderecos.idPlanosClientes
WHERE 
    clientes.bloqueado = 's' AND 
    enderecos.tipoEndereco = 'i'
```

Se estiver o MySQLi troque o `s` e o `i` por uma intorrgação `?` o tipo de dados é especificado somente em `bind_param()`.

Answer (score 1):

Está estranho tua consulta. Dei uma ajeitada na query como acredito que deveria ser.

```
SELECT 
    clientes.idClientes, 
    clientes.nome, 
    clientes.bloqueado, 
    planosclientes.idPlanos, 
    planos.nome, 
    enderecos.bairro, 
    enderecos.cidade                    
FROM 
    planosclientes 
INNER JOIN 
    clientes  ON planosclientes.idClientes       = clientes.idClientes
INNER JOIN 
    planos    ON planosclientes.idPlanos         = planos.idPlanos
INNER JOIN 
    enderecos ON planosclientes.idPlanosClientes = enderecos.idPlanosClientes
WHERE 
    clientes.bloqueado = 's' AND 
    enderecos.tipoEndereco = 'i'
```